Looking for the right approach to notify all ecs instances from a message
I am using AWS
Basically I have a websocket connection from the client to an ecs service. It is likely there will be multiple instances of this service.
I effectively want each instance of the ecs service to receive all messages so the data can be sent to the web client via the web socket connection.
I have been looking as SNS and SQS but this only seems to send it to 1 instance of the service.
What is the right approach here?
